# Play: populating a helper select from Java

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, template-engine

I have to populate an HTML select with ids and labels. I also need the labels to be ordered alphabetically.

If I pass a `List<String>` of labels, I lose `id`s. If I pass a `Map<String,String>`, I have `id`s, but the ordering is not kept.

My page:

```
@(countries: Map[String,String], myForm: Form[JUG], title: String) @header(title)
...
@helper.select(myForm("countryId"), helper.options(countries) )
```

How can I populate the HTML select with `id`s and labels alphabetically ordered?

I have to use the helper to keep the selected element between requests.

Comment: If you use `LinkedHashMap` as the implementation of `Map` you may keep the order of how objects were inserted.

Comment: @gtgaxiola Thanks! Which one, the Java one or the scala one?

Comment: Shouldn't matter `This class implements mutable maps using a hashtable. The iterator and all traversal methods of this class visit elements in the order they were inserted. `  [Scala's LinkedHashMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap)

Comment: @gtgaxiola if you transform your comments into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `LinkedHashMap` as the implementation of `Map` you may keep the order of how objects were inserted.

Shouldn't matter if using [Scala's](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap) or [Java's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) implementation.

> This class implements mutable maps using a hashtable. The iterator and all traversal methods of this class visit elements in the order they were inserted.